# CreateResponse in ASP.NET Core 2.0 for Braintree integration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I realise that ASP.NET Core no longer has HttpResponseMessage and that I need to return something like

```
    public IActionResult Blah()
    {

        return Ok(
            myservice.function()
        );
    }
```

However I'm trying to integrate Braintree payments and the code that I have has the following:

```
        var request = new TransactionRequest
        {
            Amount = model.ChargeAmount,
            PaymentMethodNonce = model.Nonce,
            Options = new TransactionOptionsRequest
            {
                SubmitForSettlement = true
            }
        };

        Result<Transaction> result = gateway.Transaction.Sale(request);
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(result);
        return response;
```

How do I convert this to something I can use with .net core 2.0?

Comment: You just need to return the result as you used to:
public ActionResult GetMeMyTransactionRequest()
        {
... Your code
            return Ok(result);
        }

Comment: But I believe this code creates a custom response from the braintree api?

Comment: What's wrong with `return Ok(result);`?

Comment: `Result<Transaction>` is a custom class, `Request.CreateResponse(result)` is likely returning a JSON so you are most likely just fine with `return Ok(gateway.Transaction.Sale(request))`